# Room not found/ accessible in io object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Currently trying to learn how socket.io works and to create a room based game, but having trouble to get clients to the same room after trying to move my code in a seperated file.

If I use the same code from game.js in my app.js file within `io.on("connection")...` i´m able to access the room and put players in the same room.

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
var http = require("http");
const game = require("./core/game/game");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;
const index = require("./routes/index");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
/

app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));
app.use("/", index);

// Reduce the logging output of Socket.IO
/* io.set('log level',1); */

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");
  game.initGame(io, socket);
     
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on *:${port}`);
});
```

game.js

```
var io;
var gameSocket;

/**
 * This function is called by index.js to initialize a new game instance.
 *
 * @param sio The Socket.IO library
 * @param socket The socket object for the connected client.
 */
exports.initGame = function (sio, socket) {
  io = sio;
  gameSocket = socket;
  gameSocket.emit("connected", { message: "You are connected!" });

  // Host Events
  gameSocket.on("hostCreateNewGame", createRoom);
  /*  gameSocket.on("hostRoomFull", hostPrepareGame);
  gameSocket.on("hostCountdownFinished", hostStartGame);
  gameSocket.on("hostNextRound", hostNextRound); */

  // Player Events
  gameSocket.on("playerJoinGame", addPlayer);
  /* gameSocket.on("playerAnswer", playerAnswer);
  gameSocket.on("playerRestart", playerRestart); */
};

async function createRoom(data) {
  console.log("Create Session");
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.username);
  var gameId = (Math.random() * 100000) | 0;
  console.log(data.username);
  console.log(gameId);
  //gameSocket.username = username;
  gameSocket.join(gameId);
}

async function addPlayer(data) {
  console.log("JOIN Session");
  console.log(data.gameId);
  //console.log(socket.username);
  const clients = await io.in(data.gameId).allSockets();
  console.log(clients);
  if (!clients) {
    console.error("[INTERNAL ERROR] Room creation failed!");
  }

  if (clients.size === 0) {
    console.log("room does not exist");
    return;
  }

  console.log(await io.in(data.gameId).allSockets());
  gameSocket.username = data.username;
  gameSocket.join(gameId);
  console.log(await io.in(data.gameId).allSockets());
  io.to(data.gameId).emit("joinSuccess", { message: "JUHU" });
```

If I try to use this code, the clients are always undefined which means I cannot the room from my current io object

`const clients = await gameSocket.in(data.gameId).allSockets();  //undefined`

Can someone show me what I would need to change in order to access the right io object and find the rooms. Maybe I´m trying to follow a bad approach here when trying to seperate the code from my app.js file.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is the gameId same in both functions?

Comment: gameId is send from the clients and I´m using the created one in my "addPlayer" call. Yes it is the same. The output of `allSockets` is `Set {}`

Comment: You probably already checked it but you are calling hostCreateNewGame only once and playerJoinGame multiple times right.

Comment: Yes exactly. But nevertheless, as far as I understand this, it should not be relevant as long as you reference the same roomName in my case gameId?!

Comment: I do not understand why this should not work. If you are in a rush and still want modularization I would suggest separate out a file for adding all the event handlers and keep your io object and related functions in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working finally.

The issue was that this returned a real number

`var gameId = (Math.random() * 100000) | 0;`

Whereas the value send to addPlayers function was a String...